# Laravel 5 Cron doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, cron, command, laravel-artisan

I am not sure why cron doesn't for Laravel artisan commands. But when I launch it manually like `php artisan my:command` it works.

I have put command in Kernel:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('my:command')->everyMinute();
}
```

Also when I run `php artisan schedule:run` it says: *No scheduled commands are ready to run*.

Crontab looks like this:

```
* * * * * php /project/artisan schedule:run
```

At first I thought maybe cron itself doesn't work, but it executes php files not related to artisan.

I am using **PHP7** if it changes anything.

---

***UPDATED*** (cron artisan commands work, but schedule dont)

**Cron command works** (log has been saved in storage/app folder)

```
* * * * * php /project/artisan command:test
```

**Cron schedule doesn't work**

```
* * * * * php /project/artisan schedule:run
```

**test.php**

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Storage;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class test extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'command:test';

    protected $description = 'Command description';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Storage::prepend('test.log', Carbon::now());
    }
}
```

**Kernel.php**

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\test::class,
    ];


    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('command:test')->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you put the full path to artisan in your cron table?

Comment: Yes.Its my full path. Also if I call that command manually with full path,it works.

Comment: Try to log something to see if your code is executed.

Comment: Its executing if I call it manualy with php /project/artisan my:command. But in cron its not.

Comment: can you try something like this

 cd /var/www/mylaravelapp/ && /usr/bin/php artisan my:command 

And: keep in mind that the environment variables might be different when you call the command via cron.

Comment: @herrjeh42 This works via cli: `root@user:/project/artisan# /usr/bin/php artisan my:command` , but in cron with full php path doesnt.

Comment: @herrjeh42 I updated my post. It seems only schedule:run doesn't work. Command works through cron. But why? I had same code and it was running with schedule before..

Comment: one step ahead - I would try to figure out in laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php::buildCommand what's going on next.

Comment: Let the OS/cron tell you what is going wrong. Could be permissions, could be environment variables. Let cron tell you what the issue is with something like: * * * * * /usr/local/opt/php56/bin/php /var/www/heyaldaAPI/artisan schedule:run > /var/log/cron/crontab.log 2>/var/log/crontab_error.log